# DivideByZeroException not working and giving out random integers (such as 8)

Tags: c#

```
    {
            **result4 = num1 / num2;** 
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write(name + " this is the final result of Divsion = " + result4);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);  
    }
    else if (op == "^") 
    {
            result5 = Math.Pow(num1, num2); 
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write(name + " this is the final result of exponential calculations = " + result5);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);  
    } 
    else
    {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
           Console.WriteLine(name + " this operant does not match the listed operant...this terminal will be cleared and closed after any key is pressed");
           Console.ReadKey();
           Environment.Exit(0);  
    }    
}          
**catch(DivideByZeroException)**
{
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(name + " you can not divide by zero; math error");
}
```

This is part of the script...but this is the main part of the error. If need be I will post the full script. The two asterisks on top of the word result 4, and catch, is to indicate the two-piece of codes.

Comment: Make sure you aren't looking at _first chance exceptions_.  In the **Debug.Windows.Exception Settings** window clear the **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** checkbox

Comment: Exactly, what are Debug.Exception settings?

Comment: In Visual Studio, click the **Debug** menu.  In the menu that appears select **Windows**, then **Exception Settings**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: So, essentially if you are using a double, the program will unable to throw a divide by zero exception?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for feedback. I agree that it was not the right change - rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know double 0 can actually be something like 0,000000001. Meaning that is not dividing by zero, but dividing with a very small number, leading to close to infinity as a result, which you are getting.

In this very example you can simply test if your num2 is close enough to zero, and if so, throw an exception.

```
If(Math.Abs(num2) < 0,00001)
    Throw DivideByZeroException
```

Comment: There are numerous posts about comparing double values, that for sure provide wider and deeper knowledge than mine :)